# IBM Cognos: matching multiple columns (two foreign keys)

Tags: cognos

I am learning how to use IBM Cognos and my first task is to create relationships between the tables I have uploaded into Cognos.

Basically, I am trying to tell Cognos to link the id column in the Person Table with the person_id and related_person_id columns in the Relationship Table, as shown here:

[image]

However, this does not seem possible since the Match Selected Columns button becomes disabled when I try to also link the related_person_id column.

The reason I need to do this is because person_id and related_person_id are foreign keys - they point to people in the Person Table and explain how they are related.

How can this be accomplished in Cognos?

Thank you.

Comment: You basically need to "alias" Person table so that you have end up with three tables. I don't know if Cognos is capable of this.

Comment: That's assuming a bridge table scenario.  The balance of probabilities is that this is the case but you should not make assumptions before you know -- and the OP knows.   CA is capable of creating views etc. and the setting to set a query subject as a bridge table is an advanced property.   Just bung in the keys of the relationships into the bridge table, define the relationships, and set the query subject usage property to bridge.  Right now the OP needs to identify what scenario or pattern he is dealing with and deal with the UI.

Comment: I could fire off a series of question to get the OP to clarify, but in my experience they don't understand or don'y respond. So I'll start with an assumption and see how that goes. I do completely agree that assumptions are a bad place to start from

Answer (score 0):

You can have any number of matches.  You need to match a single query item from each side for each match.    IIRC, a query item can be used in multiple matches, although that would only be really helpful once relational operators are implemented.

It isn't clear if in your case you want to use person_id and related_person_id as a composite key or if you want a 1.n relationship between ID and person_id and some other relationship (n.1?) between ID and related person ID or if a 1.n relationship between ID and person_id would be sufficient to whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Editorial comment:

It would be really really nice if Cognos introduced relational operators Real Soon Now.